# breezeManager.createEntity() fails to populate foreign key property for a specific value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, breeze

I have two relevant tables here:

```
public partial class List
{...
        public int RegionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
...}

public partial class Region
{
    public Region()
    {
        Lists = new HashSet<List>();
    }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Added { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the contents of the Regions table:

```
RegionId    Name
1   Global
2   China
3   USA
4   UK
8   Canada
9   Spain
10  France
```

On the breeze side of things, I pull down the Regions:

```
var query = new breeze.EntityQuery().from("Regions").select("RegionId,Name").orderBy("RegionId");
    return $rootScope.breezeManager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
        service.regions = data.results;
```

It seems to work:

```
service.regions[2]; // Name: "USA", RegionId: 3
```

However, when I try to create a new entity:

```
var newList = $rootScope.breezeManager.createEntity('List', listValues);
```

And in listValues, I specify `{ RegionId: 3, ...}`:

```
newList.RegionId // 3
newList.Region   // null
```

That would be strange already perhaps, but the **really** frustrating thing is, if I specify another value, like 1, it works. Same for 2, and 4:

```
newList.RegionId     // 1
newList.Region.Name  // "Global"
```

I've been poring through the code (and the internet) for hours trying to figure this out, but it's eluded me, and thus qualifies for my *first ever SO question!*

### Update

I'm now even more confused. I planned to workaround this by manually setting the Region after the `createEntity` call, so I added this line of code right above `createEntity`:

```
var region = Enumerable.From(service.regions).Single("$.RegionId == " + listValues.RegionId);
```

However, after doing so, and with no other changes, `newList` now correctly gets a populated `Region`, even for 3 (USA)! I then commented out that line and tried again, and it still worked. Tried a few other times, various combinations of things, and now it's not working again, even with that line. Not sure if that helps. I'll keep experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do exactly but I do see that you have a fundamental misunderstanding.

I believe you are expecting your first query to return `Region` entities and you think that `service.regions` is populated with `Region` entities in the success callback.

Neither is true. Your query contains a [`select()` clause](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_select) which makes it what we call a **projection**. A projection **returns data objects, not entities**. There are no `Region` entities in cache either.

> You may have seen elsewhere - perhaps a Pluralsight video - where a projection query did return entities. That happens when the query includes a [`toType` clause](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_toType) which actually casts the projected data into instances of the targeted type. That's a trick you should only perform with great care, knowing what you are doing, why, and the limitations. But you're not casting in this query so this digression is besides the point.

It follows that the `service.regions` array holds some data *objects* that contain `Region` data but it does not hold `Region` *entities*.

This also explains why, when you created a new `List` entity with `RegionId:3`, the new entity's `Region` property returned `null`. Of course it is `null`. Based only on what you've told us, there are no `Region` entities in cache at all, let alone a `Region` with id=3.

I can't explain how you're able to get a `Region` with id=1 or id=2. I'm guessing there is something you haven't told us ... like you acquired these regions by way of some other query.

I don't understand why you're using a projection query in the first place. Why not just query for all regions and be done with it?

```
 breeze.EntityQuery.from("Regions").orderBy("RegionId")
       .using(manager).execute(function(data) { 
           service.regions = data.results;
       });
```

I don't understand your update at all; that doesn't look like a valid EF query to me.

#### Tangential issues

First, why are you using a `HashSet<List>` to initialize the `Lists` property in your server-side `Region` model class? That's a specialized collection type that only confuses matters here. It doesn't do what the casual reader might think it does. While it prevents someone from adding the same object reference twice, it doesn't do the more important job of preventing someone from adding two different `List` objects with the same `RegionId`. The simple, obvious, and correct thing to do is ...

```
Lists = new System.Collections.Generic.List<List>();

// the full type name is only necessary because you burned the name "List"
// when defining your model class.
```

Second, on the client-side, please don't extend the Angular `$rootScope` with anything. That kind of global variable "pollution" is widely regarded as "bad practice". Keep your Breeze stuff inside a proper Angular service and inject that service when you need something.

Comment: Thank you @Ward, that was very helpful! Removing the projection seems to have fixed the issue. The reason I was doing the projection in the first place was to request less data on the wire (to avoid bringing down the Added datetime), but it's not a big deal.

Regarding the update, that wasn't an EF query, it was a linq.js select statement.

Regarding the HashSet, the EF code-first generator actually created that for me, it wasn't my doing *shrug* And good point about $rootScope, I'll make that change, thanks again!